# SQL Select row depending on values in different columns

Tags: sql, row

I've already found so many answers here but now I can't seem to find any to my specific problem.

I can't figure out how to select a value from a row depending on the value in different columns

with the below table, I want to achieve the following results.

[image]

in case the value in column `stdvpuni = 1` then return values / contents from this row for the article (column art).

in case the value in column `stdvpuni = 0` then return values / contents from the row where `STDUNIABG = 1` for this article (column art).

[image]

Comment: Use [SQL Case Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Comment: @keivanIpchi: it's a CASE **expression** and the link shows the poor quality of w3fools once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want one row part `art`, based on the content of other rows.  That suggests using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by art order by stdvpuni desc, STDUNIABG desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You don't specify what to do if neither column is `1`.  You might want a `where` clause (`where 1 in (stdvpuni, STDUNIABG)`) or another condition in the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what values / contents is, but I suppose that's easy for you to figure out. So, I will focus on the way to select this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN current.stdvpuni = 1 THEN 'values / contents of current row'
    ELSE 'values / contents of other row'
END
FROM yourtable current
JOIN yourtable other
ON other.stdvpuni = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your conditions with `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1 
WHERE t1.STDVPUNI = 1 
   OR (
        t1.STDVPUNI = 0 AND t1.STDUNIABG = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.ART = t1.ART AND t2.STDVPUNI = 1)
      );
```